# Output of select query issue

Tags: php, mysql

In the query below I am attempting to select the user's profile picture and output it. My insert query and select query is working (I believe). Right now, I can upload the image and the user's user_id is associated with the image in my database. Then in my select query I am attempting to select the image associated with that user.

My database for this is simple and only has the following within it... `id, user_id, img`.

I believe the issue may reside with my output, here:

```
<img id="profile-pic" src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "profile_images/default.jpg"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />
```

I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Does anyone see if I am outputting this wrong? Right now, the default image loads upon page load, however, once I upload an image for a user it displays, but if I reload the page, the image goes back to the default.

```
function getPhoto($con,$dest)
    {
        $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" ); //added

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `user_id` = '$user_id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");

        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            return $row;

        return 0;
    }


// Make sure all functions above are include here

// Get the database connection
$con        =   Connection();
// Check for post   
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        // Try uploading
        $upload =   UploadFile($_FILES);
        // If upload fails
        if(!$upload['success'])
            echo '<h3>Sorry, an error occurred</h3>';
        else {
                // You could add error handling here based on the results of 
                // each function's success or failure below.

                // Try to save it
                $saveToDb   =   SaveToDb($con,$upload['file']['dest']);
                // Get the profile from image name
                $profPic    =   ($saveToDb)? getPhoto($con,$upload['file']['dest']) : false; ?>


                <?php
            }
    }
?>
<img id="profile-pic" src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "profile_images/default.jpg"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile" onchange="readURL(this);">
    <img width="400px" height="300px" id="file" src="#" alt="your image">
    <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Change the return value in your `getPhoto()` from return `$row` to `$row['img']` in your result above you are returning the whole column instead of the image column only

Comment: Also your $profPic is checking if data wa sinserted into the database. Since if you refresh no data is inserted into database the default is shown. So just assign a seperate unconditional statement to `$profPic` that only fetches data from database

Comment: Doing this stops the uploaded photo from being displayed (selected).

Comment: I think this is what I need...just not sure how.... So just assign a seperate unconditional statement to $profPic that only fetches data from database

Comment: Yea you can just make `$profPic = getPhoto($con,$dest);` That should do it

Comment: What is `Connection()`? You aren't using prepared statements here and are open to SQL injections. `empty` checks for `0`.-http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @Abolarinstephen that did the trick! Create an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @chris85 What do you mean with the empty?

Comment: `!empty($profPic)` accounts for `0` not being a value present, so you don't need `&& $profPic != 0`.

Comment: @chris85 Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Well it was the least important part of what I posted but if you follow the `empty` link supplied you should see, under the `The following things are considered to be empty:` section.

Comment: @Becky I'm happy I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `$profPic` the way you called it would not allow for the data to be shown on page refresh because on page refresh no data is inserted.

Yea you can just change it to:

```
$profPic = getPhoto($con,$dest);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your Code you have called your `getPhoto()` function on submit of your form, so it obviously when you refresh page that function will not triger as its been called in `if (isset($_POST['create']))` which will be false on page refresh.

so if you want to display Image every time just call this function on `$_SESSION['user']` that will display your image every time.

let me know if you still face problem.